# Vertically align two labels

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I want to vertically align two UILabels. One contains the description(maximum of 3 lines lines) and other contains the number.
Like this

[image]

I tried my best, but I could only manage to create one like this. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will work:

```
#define kDescriptionWidth 200

...

- (void)alignNumLabel:(UILabel *)numLabel withDescriptionLabel:(UILabel *)descriptionLabel topLeftPoint:(CGPoint)topLeftPoint {
    numLabel.frame = CGRectMake(topLeftPoint.x, topLeftPoint.y, 0, 0);
    [numLabel sizeToFit];

    CGSize maxDescriptionSize = CGSizeMake(kDescriptionWidth, (descriptionLabel.numberOfLines == 0 ? CGFLOAT_MAX : descriptionLabel.font.lineHeight * descriptionLabel.numberOfLines));
    CGSize labelSize = [descriptionLabel.text sizeWithFont:descriptionLabel.font constrainedToSize:maxDescriptionSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    descriptionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(numLabel.frame) + 5, numLabel.frame.origin.y, labelSize.width, labelSize.height);
}
```

To use it, do something like:

```
[self alignNumLabel:numLabel withDescriptionLabel:descriptionLabel topLeftPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10)];
[self alignNumLabel:numLabel2 withDescriptionLabel:descriptionLabel2 topLeftPoint:CGPointMake(10, CGRectGetMaxY(descriptionLabel.frame) + 10)];
```

Let me know if you have any questions about how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used it. but the issue is, descriptionLabel only have 1 line. (I have set descriptionLabel number of lines = 0).

Comment: Got it. I set descriptionLabel number of lines=2. Now it seems ok. Thanks a lot

Comment: The `numberOfLines` property sets the maximum number of lines, it can still be less than that if there is less text. Setting it to 0 means it can have unlimited lines and would need to be dealt with differently. In your question you stated that it would have a maximum of 3 lines, so that's why it's done that way.

Comment: Yes, I just test with number of of lines 2. Now I can change it as relevant. Thanks a lot for the answer, highly appreciated it...

Comment: I just made a small change to the code so it works with `descriptionLabel.numberOfLines == 0`, just in case you want to allow unlimited lines later.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to change the height of the first label to fit only one line. When you do so the number will go up automatically.

Comment: But the issue is, If description Label contains only 1 line, then alignment goes wrong.